# How to initialize children component after parent?

Tags: angular, angular8

I have component that has a service dependency:

```
<lib-reon-map-library> </lib-reon-map-library>
```

On this level there are some other components:

```
<lib-reon-map-library> </lib-reon-map-library>
<app-search></app-search>
```

How to initialize `<app-search></app-search>` after `<lib-reon-map-library> </lib-reon-map-library>` when all dependencies of `<lib-reon-map-library> </lib-reon-map-library>` is ready?

So, component where I first run service:

```
export class ReonMapLibraryComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
  constructor(private reonMap: ReonMapLibraryService) {}
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.reonMap.initialization(this.mapContainer.nativeElement as HTMLElement);
  }
}
```

Service is:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: "root"
})
export class ReonMapLibraryService {
}
```

Then I have registered this service in module:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [ReonMapLibraryComponent, MenuToolsComponent],
  exports: [ReonMapLibraryComponent, MenuToolsComponent]
})
export class ReonMapLibraryModule {}
```

And then I import this module `ReonMapLibraryModule` to another poject Angular in module `AppModule`:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [

  ],
  imports: [
    ReonMapLibraryModule,

  ],
  providers: [{ provide: LOCALE_ID, useValue: "ru" }, SearchHistoryService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate more on what all happens before `<lib-reon-map-library>` finally loads and renders to the DOM? You could very well use a shared service on which you could set a flag which would then be listened to by the parent of `app-search` and then toggle the condition that then renders it via an `*ngIf`. But then it would depend on what all does lib-reon-map-library` require to load. It might have a dependency on an API call that might take time to load.

Comment: Okay, I will shared <lib-reon-map-library> and component

Comment: Check question again

Comment: What is `this.mapContainer.nativeElement` used for?

Comment: then you need to move <app-search></app-search>
under the <lib-reon-map-library> </lib-reon-map-library>

Comment: it is reference with HTML element

Comment: I hve moved `<app-search></app-search> ` it is the same result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `<ng-content>` to conditionally create dependent components without exposing logic.

```html
<lib-reon-map-library>
   <app-search></app-search>
</lib-reon-map-library>
```

```js
@Component({
   selector: 'lib-reon-map-library',
   template: `<ng-content *ngIf="ready$ | async"></ng-content>`
})
export class LibReonMapLibraryComponent {
    read$: Observable<any>; // emits when component is ready
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set a flag `isReady = false` and initialize `<app-search>` only when it is true.

When your service dependency is ready, emit event to parent component and set `isReady` to `true`

Try like this:

reon-map-library  component

```
@Output() DependencyReady = new EventEmitter() 

// on ready
this.service.getData().subscribe(res => {
    this.DependencyReady.emit();
})
```

parent-component:

.ts

```
isReady:boolean = false
```

.html

```
<lib-reon-map-library (DependencyReady )="isReady = true"> </lib-reon-map-library>

<app-search *ngIf="isReady"></app-search>
```

Comment: I dont have HTTP request, I have simple initialization new A() in service.

Comment: This will work but it can be somehow dirty. Why not encapsulate <app-search></app-search> inside the <lib-reon-map-library> </lib-reon-map-library> and pass the data from the service call

Comment: @OPV I just assumed a http call, emit it whenever it is ready

Comment: @JackM Nice suggesion, another answer has been added based on that

Comment: Can you share it in stackbiltz?